# Scripted letters in Powerpoint math?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-powerpoint, latex

**(1)** In LaTeX, I can produce scripted letters by using `\mathscr` from the `mathrsfs` package, e.g.

```
$\mathscr{X}$,
$\mathscr{U}$,
$\mathscr{S}$
```

[image]

**(2)** However, when I use these commands in Word LaTeX mode, I get very different results:

[image]

**(3)** These look more like what can be obtained in LaTeX by using calligraphed letters rather than scripted:

```
$\mathcal{X}$,
$\mathcal{U}$,
$\mathcal{S}$
```

[image]

How can I obtain truly scripted letters which look like (1) in Microsoft Powerpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you are using a different font in your other program.

You probably have to install the font from LaTex then use it in PowerPoint/Word

Does [the answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/579089/the-same-font-as-latex-for-powerpoint) give you good direction?

Comment: Thanks, the link pointed me into the right direction. FTR: Install XITS math font, use it, and you're fine. https://github.com/aliftype/xits/releases